# Add Python keys to table column

Tags: python

I have 4 APIs to call as below:

```python
APIs = {
    "ApiA": "api1.abc.com",
    "ApiB": "api2.abc.com",
    "ApiC": "api3.abc.com",
    "ApiD": "api4.abc.com"
}

My code look like this 
    def create_table(json):
        table = []
        for data in json:
        name = data.get("name", "")
        table.append(
            [
                 name,
                 get_nam(name),
                 data.get("Functn1", ""),
                 data.get("Functn2", ""),
                 data.get("get_api", ""),
    
    def get_api(i):
        get_name = APIs.get(i)
            return(get_name)

    assync def main():
        for instance in APIs.keys():
        #some other code related to user/passwrd
            async with httpx.AsyncClient(
                verify=False,
                data = await Functn4(instance, async_session)
            df = create_table(data)
            print(df);
```

With abovefunction I get the data from the apis in a single table like this:

```
   Column1  Column2  Column3 Column4
    Row1       Row2    Row3
    Row11      Row12   Row13
    Row21      Row22   Row23
    Row31      Row32   Row33
```

Now I want to add APIs key to column4 based on which api the data is coming from. Which should look like this:

```
    Column1  Column2  Column3 Column4
    Row1       Row2    Row3     ApiA
    Row11      Row12   Row13    ApiB
    Row21      Row22   Row23    ApiC
    Row31      Row32   Row33    ApiD
```

Please help

I am getting the data from all apis, but want to know which data is coming from which api

Comment: You haven't shown us any code at all.  Are you using pandas?  If so, this is as easy as `df['Column4'] = list(APIs.keys())`.

Comment: Pass the dictionary key to the function that performs the API query. Then it can add that to the results table.

Comment: I added my code, hope that makes sense to you

Comment: That's not valid Python code.

Comment: I am able to resolve it, I passed the dictionary key to the function that has API query and use df.loc[df.Colmn1 != NameError, “NewColumnName”] = API